# CSV file with XML entries

Tags: xml, csv

I have a CSV file which contains in its fourth column of XML entries. Each cells in this column looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns1:PutReisInformatieBoodschapIn xmlns:ns1="urn:ndov:cdm:trein:reisinformatie:messages:dynamischeaankomststaat:1" xmlns:ns2="urn:ndov:cdm:trein:reisinformatie:data:4"><ns2:ReisInformatieProductDAS TimeStamp="2019-01-01T03:00:07.609Z" Versie="6.1"><ns2:RIPAdministratie><ns2:ReisInformatieProductID>1901010400072200004</ns2:ReisInformatieProductID><ns2:AbonnementId>55</ns2:AbonnementId><ns2:ReisInformatieTijdstip>2019-01-01T03:00:00.000Z</ns2:ReisInformatieTijdstip></ns2:RIPAdministratie><ns2:DynamischeAankomstStaat><ns2:RitId>1413</ns2:RitId><ns2:RitDatum>2019-01-01</ns2:RitDatum><ns2:RitStation><ns2:StationCode>SHL</ns2:StationCode><ns2:Type>6</ns2:Type><ns2:KorteNaam>Schiphol</ns2:KorteNaam><ns2:MiddelNaam>Schiphol Airport</ns2:MiddelNaam><ns2:LangeNaam>Schiphol Airport</ns2:LangeNaam><ns2:UICCode>8400561</ns2:UICCode></ns2:RitStation><ns2:TreinAankomst><ns2:TreinNummer>1413</ns2:TreinNummer><ns2:TreinNaam>Nachtnettrein</ns2:TreinNaam><ns2:TreinSoort Code="IC">Intercity</ns2:TreinSoort><ns2:TreinStatus>2</ns2:TreinStatus><ns2:Vervoerder>NS</ns2:Vervoerder><ns2:TreinHerkomst InfoStatus="Gepland"><ns2:StationCode>UT</ns2:StationCode><ns2:Type>6</ns2:Type><ns2:KorteNaam>Utrecht C</ns2:KorteNaam><ns2:MiddelNaam>Utrecht C.</ns2:MiddelNaam><ns2:LangeNaam>Utrecht Centraal</ns2:LangeNaam><ns2:UICCode>8400621</ns2:UICCode></ns2:TreinHerkomst><ns2:TreinHerkomst InfoStatus="Actueel"><ns2:StationCode>UT</ns2:StationCode><ns2:Type>6</ns2:Type><ns2:KorteNaam>Utrecht C</ns2:KorteNaam><ns2:MiddelNaam>Utrecht C.</ns2:MiddelNaam><ns2:LangeNaam>Utrecht Centraal</ns2:LangeNaam><ns2:UICCode>8400621</ns2:UICCode></ns2:TreinHerkomst><ns2:PresentatieTreinHerkomst><ns2:Uitingen><ns2:Uiting>Utrecht C.</ns2:Uiting></ns2:Uitingen></ns2:PresentatieTreinHerkomst><ns2:AankomstTijd InfoStatus="Gepland">2019-01-01T03:00:00.000Z</ns2:AankomstTijd><ns2:AankomstTijd InfoStatus="Actueel">2019-01-01T03:01:36.000Z</ns2:AankomstTijd><ns2:ExacteAankomstVertraging>PT1M36S</ns2:ExacteAankomstVertraging><ns2:PresentatieAankomstVertraging><ns2:Uitingen><ns2:Uiting>+1 min.</ns2:Uiting></ns2:Uitingen></ns2:PresentatieAankomstVertraging><ns2:GedempteAankomstVertraging>PT0S</ns2:GedempteAankomstVertraging><ns2:TreinAankomstSpoor InfoStatus="Gepland"><ns2:SpoorNummer>5</ns2:SpoorNummer></ns2:TreinAankomstSpoor><ns2:TreinAankomstSpoor InfoStatus="Gepland"><ns2:SpoorNummer>6</ns2:SpoorNummer></ns2:TreinAankomstSpoor><ns2:TreinAankomstSpoor InfoStatus="Actueel"><ns2:SpoorNummer>6</ns2:SpoorNummer></ns2:TreinAankomstSpoor><ns2:PresentatieTreinAankomstSpoor><ns2:Uitingen><ns2:Uiting>6</ns2:Uiting></ns2:Uitingen></ns2:PresentatieTreinAankomstSpoor><ns2:VerkorteRouteHerkomst InfoStatus="Gepland"><ns2:Station><ns2:StationCode>ASD</ns2:StationCode><ns2:Type>6</ns2:Type><ns2:KorteNaam>Amsterdam</ns2:KorteNaam><ns2:MiddelNaam>Amsterdam C.</ns2:MiddelNaam><ns2:LangeNaam>Amsterdam Centraal</ns2:LangeNaam><ns2:UICCode>8400058</ns2:UICCode></ns2:Station></ns2:VerkorteRouteHerkomst><ns2:VerkorteRouteHerkomst InfoStatus="Actueel"><ns2:Station><ns2:StationCode>ASD</ns2:StationCode><ns2:Type>6</ns2:Type><ns2:KorteNaam>Amsterdam</ns2:KorteNaam><ns2:MiddelNaam>Amsterdam C.</ns2:MiddelNaam><ns2:LangeNaam>Amsterdam Centraal</ns2:LangeNaam><ns2:UICCode>8400058</ns2:UICCode></ns2:Station></ns2:VerkorteRouteHerkomst><ns2:PresentatieVerkorteRouteHerkomst><ns2:Uitingen><ns2:Uiting>Amsterdam C.</ns2:Uiting></ns2:Uitingen></ns2:PresentatieVerkorteRouteHerkomst><ns2:WijzigingHerkomst><ns2:WijzigingType>11</ns2:WijzigingType></ns2:WijzigingHerkomst><ns2:WijzigingHerkomst><ns2:WijzigingType>40</ns2:WijzigingType></ns2:WijzigingHerkomst></ns2:TreinAankomst></ns2:DynamischeAankomstStaat></ns2:ReisInformatieProductDAS></ns1:PutReisInformatieBoodschapIn>
```

I would like to get all of these entries in one XML file to process that data. How could this be done? I tried in Python reading each entry as a string and parse it into a XML, but this only works with making separate XML files, see code below. As the csv has more than 130000 entries, this is not ideal. In there a better way to do this? I am fairly new to programming in Python and using XML, so I might not understand everything.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xmlschema

n = 100
df = pd.read_csv("InfoPlusDAS_2019-01-01.csv/InfoPlusDAS_2019-01-01.csv", header = None, nrows=n)
#print(df)
for i in range(n):
    data = df[2][i]
    root = ET.fromstring(data)
    element = ET.ElementTree(root)
    f =  open("myxmlfile" +str(i)+".xml", "wb")
    element.write(f)
    f.close()
```

Thanks for the help in advance
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfJUJ.png

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's always good to post what your desired outcome should be. In your case, do you want `<?xml><ns1..><ns2:..></ns2><ns2:..></ns2><ns2:..>..</ns2></ns1></xml>` ? If not, please give *simplified* example. There is no reason to post 4kb XML snippet.

Comment: I would like to get the XML string out of every cells of the CSV in one XML file, such that I can do a data analysis. So for example in the CSV are two cells with <?XML><ns1><ns2>...</ns2></ns1></xml>, then I would like to add them together to <?XML><ns1><ns2>...</ns2></ns1><ns1><ns2>...</ns2></ns1></xml>